# jQuery: Detect if there was an ajax call or not

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a function X the may or may not send an ajax call.
Then I have a function Y that calls X, and wants to know what happend - if the ajax call was sent or not.
I should mention that function X is a "black box" - meaning I can't change its implementation to return an indication value.

I tried using .ajaxSend(), but it's only triggered when there is an ajax call. So in the case where there was no ajax, I get no indication at all.

To get around that I tried using .promise().done() along with the .ajaxSend(), as if to say "if there was an ajax call then the ajaxSend is triggered and saves a boolean value. Then at the end the done() will be triggered and look at that boolean to determine what happened".

The problem is how to ensure that the done() won't pop before the ajaxSend?

Or is there a better way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: how about put the logic in `done()` only? just leave `.ajaxSend()`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : But then how will I know if the ajax happened or not?

Comment: if there is `.done()` , there is an AJAX call, right ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : No. If there is an ajax call then the .ajaxSend() event handler will be triggered. But if there wasn't an ajax call, it will not be triggered.
The .done() function, as far as I understand from the jQuery documentation, is triggered when all queued actions finish executing on a particular element. But unfortunately I can't be sure that an ajax call is considered to be a "queued action". I did not understand that from the docs

Comment: i wonder what project are you working on, with a black-box function X. Is the function returns meaningful values (that indicates an AJAX call is made or not)?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : No, it doesn't return any meaningful value. Basically function Y gets X as a parameter, so I can never be sure what X is (and hence the "black box")